# How to append a panda series to a python list without index?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two csv's which are being read into two pandas dataframes df2 and df3, I am trying to compare one column to see if it exist in other column

```
    def compare_old_new(self):
     result = []
     if not self.df3.loc[~self.df3['name'].isin(self.df2['name'])].empty: 
      self.result.append(self.df3['name'].loc[~self.df3['name'].isin(self.df2['name'])]
```

this is my result as you can see the index is also being appended

```
[129    location One]
```

I do not want the index to be appended to the result.
**Update: Adding a sample of df2.head() below df3 is similar

```
    name                external_id
0  loc in 35950          227  
1  loc in 36201          240  
2  loc in 35214          164  
3  loc in 36302          242  
4  loc in 35630          390
```

Comment: Will you please show samples of `df2` and `df3`.

Comment: That is a list with a `pd.Series` in it. I dont' know what you mean by "without an index", all `pd.Series` and `pd.DataFrame` objects have indices. What you are asking doesn't make sense

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because you are appending a pd.Series to the list and you would like a plain value? Try to extract it maybe?

```
def compare_old_new(self):
    result = []
    if not self.df3.loc[~self.df3['name'].isin(self.df2['name'])].empty: 
        self.result.append(self.df3['name'].loc[~self.df3['name'].isin(self.df2['name'])].values)
```

Comment: That didnt work the output is [129    location One] where 129 is the index, what I am trying to do is append to list without index

Comment: can you try the code again I think the previous one has unmatched brackets

Comment: I did a print of the result
[array(['location One],
      dtype=object)]